Regularity structures vs Renormalization
What are the substantial differences in the theory of "Regularity Structures" versus perturbative renormalization from Quantum Field Theory?
The idea that to treat divergences inherent to path integrals, or equivalently with stochastic partial differential equations, one has to introduce a "regularization", and express final results in terms of "renormalized" quantities that remain finite as the regularization is removed, is certainly not new.
Same for the fact that these operation can be performed by a recursive subtraction, whose combinatorics is described in terms of Feynman diagrams and "forests".
Same for the fact that all of these amounts in the end to a redefinition of the parameters appearing in the Lagrangian (or in the stochastic PDE).
So, where is the beef?
Is this "just" a formalization of these ideas in terms of well defined mathematical structures, or does one allow to compute things and maybe predict new phenomena?

Might be good to compare the BPHZ theorem in the theory of regularity structures https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.08138 to the BPHZ theorem in perturbative QFT https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.08634
